# How do I put a ContentPresenter in a Toolbar

Tags: wpf, xaml, toolbar, contentpresenter

I am struggling to put a ContentPresenter in a Toolbar. I have a UserControl, DashboardView, with a viewmodel, DashboardViewModel. My ContentPresenter is set up like so:

in the UserControl.Resources, I have:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DashboardVM:DashboardViewModel}">
     <Dashboard:DashboardView />
</DataTemplate>
```

and in the toolbar:

```
<ToolBarTray Margin="0" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <ToolBar Band="0" BanIndex="0">
        <--! other stuff -->
    <ToolBar Band="0" BandIndex="1" MinWidth="500" ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True">
          <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=DashboardViewModel}" />
    </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
```

The ContentPresenter does not appear when executing. The other ToolBar does.

I've put the ContentPresenter outside of the toolbar in a Grid and it appears fine. So it's something with the ToolBar, but I cannot figure out what.

UPDATE: I've also attempted (among many things) putting the ContentPresenter in a MenuItem, like this:

```
            <ToolBar Band="0" BandIndex="1">
                <MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem.Header>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=DashboardViewModel}"/>
                    </MenuItem.Header>
                </MenuItem>
            </ToolBar>
```

Still not showing up.

More info:

DashboardView:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Wsi.Common.View.Dashboard.DashboardView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:Dashboard="clr-namespace:Wsi.Common.ViewModel.Dashboard"
         xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Wsi.Common.View.Dashboard"
         MinWidth="500"
         MinHeight="30"
         MaxHeight="70">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Dashboard:DashboardItemViewModel}">
        <view:DashboardItemView />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel MaxHeight="70" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="fileSystemDashboardItem" Content="{Binding Path=FileSystemDashboardItemViewModel}" />
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="spreadHealthDashboardItem" Content="{Binding Path=SpreadHealthDashboardItemViewModel}" />
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="spreadStatsDashboardItem" Content="{Binding Path=SpreadStatsDashboardItemViewModel}" />
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="acquisitionStatsDashboardItem" Content="{Binding Path=AcquisitionStatsDashboardItemViewModel}" />
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="backhaulHealthDashboardItem" Content="{Binding Path=BackhaulHealthDashboardItemViewModel}" />
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="serverHealthDashboardItem" Content="{Binding Path=ServerHealthDashboardItemViewModel}" />
</StackPanel>
```

DashboardViewModel simply holds properties as above for the sub-viewModels, just {get; set;}

As mentioned before, this worked beautifully in a row by itself in the View, above the ToolBarTray.

TIA!

Janene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question... there was nothing wrong with my code. The items in the Contents of the ContentPresenter exceeded the width of the toolbar. The toolbar displayed nothing as the contents were too wide.

An entire day chasing a bug that just needs me to make my s**t smaller and smarter about resizing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confusing a `ContentPresenter` with a `ContentControl`.

A `ContentPresenter` is used to indicate where in the visual hierarchy custom content should appear in the ControlTemplate of a ContentControl.

A `ContentControl` is an actual control that you can put in your UI.

What happens if you do this instead?

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DashboardVM:DashboardViewModel}">
     <Dashboard:DashboardView />
</DataTemplate>

<ToolBarTray Margin="0" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <ToolBar Band="0" BanIndex="0">
        <--! other stuff -->
    <ToolBar Band="0" BandIndex="1" MinWidth="500" ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True">
          <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=DashboardViewModel}" />
    </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
```

Comment: ContentControl gives me the same result.

I have used this exact construct in an independent window and it worked beautifully. 

"If there is a DataTemplate associated with the type of Content, the ContentPresenter applies that DataTemplate to the Content property and the resulting UIElement and its child elements, if any, are displayed."

Based on this from MSDN, I'm baffled:

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with your `DashboardViewModel` or `DashboardView`? Could you edit your question and add those?

Comment: I've added DashboardView. 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, it looks like again you have ContentPresenters instead of ContentControls for your view. What happens if you change *all* your ContentPresenter tags to ContentControl (including any you might have in DashboardItemView or deeper)?

Comment: Same result, nothing visible. I do not show any errors in my output, either, for any of these attempts. 

Why would the ContentPresenter work outside of a ToolBar but not inside of it?

Comment: I would simplify what you're trying to do way down to just a very simple case. Temporarily replace all the contents of your DashboardView with just a label, and see if the label shows.